# karaf broker url inside docker container - windows

Tags: docker, karaf, docker-for-windows

So I am working on creating a `docker container` for a `camel` project. In the project I am sending data to a messaging queue using `apache karaf`.

Now when the project is ran normally, *i.e without as a container*, it works properly. The `karaf broker url` is - `tcp://localhost:61616`. This value is coming from a config file inside the camel project.

But when I create the `container` error is thrown -

> Cannot connect to the broker url - tcp://localhost:61616

My guess is 'localhost' inside the `docker` wouldn't be considered the `localhost` of my machine *(laptop)*. Inside the `container`, `locahost` would be it's own IP address, *I believe.*

So, **what address should I put for the broker url?** 127.0.0.1? or my laptop's external IP?

Answer (score 0):

If you camle project is running as docker container and karaf on host then you need to connect to karaf using host ip address. You can change broker url in config like below

```
tcp://host_ip:61616
```

As docker container is also like a vm and it has its own network and isolated form host, so localhost for host and container is different.

Comment: Correct. so the IP to be written is my laptop's IP, right?

Comment: cool. I'll give it a try and let you know if it's successful.